# How to make AndroidStudio build all ABIs when running an app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have an Android app, which uses JNI libraries, and supports all Android's ABIs.

When I click "run" from AndroidStudio, it only builds the libraries targetting the device's default ABI (`x86_64` on the emulator or `arm64-v8a` on a device).

I want to disable this optimization and build all ABIs when launching, how can I do that?

---

Context:

The default behavior makes sense for most apps, but my application acts as a plugin and gets dynamically loaded into other apps, some of which are 32-bit only -- therefore I need multiple ABIs embedded into the APK.

Also, as part of my unit test, I bundle `someapp-x86.apk`, `someapp-x86_64.apk`, etc, as resources of the test module and automatically installs and executes it as part of the test.

```
    def copyApkTask = task ("copy${testVariant.name.capitalize()}ApkAssets", type: Copy) {
        from tasks.getByPath(':someApp:packageArmeabi_v7aDebug')
        from tasks.getByPath(':someApp:packageArm64_v8aDebug')
        from tasks.getByPath(':someApp:packageX86Debug')
        from tasks.getByPath(':someApp:packageX86_64Debug')

        into assetTask.outputDir
        include '*.apk'
    }
```

This will work perfectly when running gradle standalone, but fails from AndroidStudio with the error

> Cannot build for ABI: x86 supported ABIs are: arm64-v8a

---

I've been trying to figure it out, and all I could find is on 
[ExternalNativeBuildTask.java#321](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/050fc0b64b5bff7ca6905c1236297479ca495578/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/ExternalNativeBuildTask.java#321). Unfortunately this seems to be from an older version of the gradle plugin.

Comment: You can get all these APKs using splits instead of custom tasks. You simply choose "build APK" instead of "Run".

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, @Alex "Build APK" works as expected, but I need to be able run and debug an app from AndroidStudio.

Comment: I'm using `productFlavors` to create the splits, because I also want to add the ABI as the applicationIdSuffix.

How would splits differ from this? 

    flavorDimensions "abi"
    productFlavors {
        for (abi in ["armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"]) {
            def safe_abi = abi.replaceAll("-", "_")
            "$safe_abi" {
                dimension "abi"
                applicationIdSuffix ".$safe_abi"
                manifestPlaceholders = [abi: abi]
                ndk {
                    abiFilter abi
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @PauloCosta, it will be better update your question for your `productFlavors` configuration.

Comment: I often find that Run and Debug don't work well for big apps and complex gradle setups. In such cases, Build APK + adb install +attach debugger is a better alternative.

Comment: I don't know what drawbacks the **productFlavors** approach for multiple ABIs has, probably **splits** build faster, but y.m.m.v. One thing for sure - with **splits** you [can choose the applicationId](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-APK-versions) as easily.